# Smooth functions satisfying an identity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $ f, g$ be smooth non constant functions from an interval $(a, b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)^2 + g(x)^2 = 1$ for all $x$ in $(a, b)$.

Is it then true that $f(x) =\cos (h(x))$ and $g(x) =\sin(h(x))$ for some smooth function $h(x)$?

Comment: Yes, it is${}$.

Comment: Yes, of course.  For any $f(x)$ fitting your conditions, you can find an $h(x)$ such that $\cos (h(x)) = f(x)$, and likewise for $g(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, really I am not recalling it (proof) well, can you suggest some link or give hint for proof?

Comment: Can't you argue by comparison sides $\arccos(f(x))=h(x)$ that $h$ has to be smooth?

Comment: @user3342072 It can't be that simple, because if $S$ is the unit circle in the plane the corresponding statement for $f,g:S\to\Bbb R$ is false. (Let $f(s+it)=s$, $g(ss+it)=t$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Consider $z(x) = f(x) + i g(x)$.  You want to find a function $h(x)$ on $[0,1]$ such that $z(x) = \exp(i h(x))$.  Note that $z' = i h' z$.  Thus you can take 
$$ h(x) = h_0 + \int_0^x \frac{ z'(t)}{i z(t)} dt = h_0 + \int_0^x (f(t) g'(t) - f'(t) g(t))\; dt$$
where $z(0) = \exp(i h_0)$.